# How to make popup form insert data to database?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I tried to make a popup form and use this form to insert data into a database.
This popup form works well, but it does not insert the information to the database. I don't know what wrong with it. Please help me.

[image: database structure]

Here is my code:

HTML code:

```
<a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">
<p align = 'center'><img src='image/add.png'></p>
</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
<form action="popup.php" method="post">
    <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
        <h3>ADD INFO</h3>
        <label for='mail' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Mail:</label>
        <input name='mail' id='mail' value='' placeholder='Mail' data-theme='a' type='text'>

        <label for='username' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Username:</label>
        <input name='username' id='username' value='' placeholder='Username' data-theme='a' type='text'>

        <label for='password' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Password:</label>
        <input name='password' id='password' value='' placeholder='Password' data-theme='a' type='text'>

        <button type="submit" name="Submit">ADD INFO</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
 $db= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if(!$db)
{
    echo "CAN'T CONNECT DATABASE";
    exit;
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("sctv_data2",$db);
if(!$db_selected)
{
    die("CAN'T USE THIS DATABASE: ".mysql_error());
}
if($_POST["mail"] !="" && $_POST["username"] != "" && $_POST["password"] !="" )
{
    $mail = $_POST["mail"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `login` VALUES ( '$mail','$username','$password')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$db);
}
```

Comment: what type error you are getting

Comment: can you post your table structure?

Comment: are you able to get post from form ?

Comment: why you are not using jqury ajax to post your data?, try it it will work

Comment: are the popup.php and HTML in the same directory?

Comment: @ barakat ali foroz it in same file popup.php

Comment: @ Arun Kumaresh, I click ADD button, it submit but not insert to database

Comment: $_POST[]
are you getting all inputs there try print $_POST[]

Comment: Silly question perhaps but the PHP code for inserting the data is called `popup.php` correct? The `popup.php` script is in the same directory as the page that has the form?

Comment: dont use mysql connection. It's better do make a PDO Connection or Mysqli connection. Mysql connection is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use it like this:

```
 $db= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if(!$db)
{
    echo "CAN'T CONNECT DATABASE";
    exit;
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("sctv_data2",$db);
if(!$db_selected)
{
    die("CAN'T USE THIS DATABASE: ".mysql_error());
}
if($_POST["mail"] !="" && $_POST["username"] != "" && $_POST["password"] !="" )
{
    $mail = $_POST["mail"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'login' (email, username, password) VALUES ( '$mail','$username','$password')";   // Use you own column name from login table
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$db);
}
```

Comment: It work, but I detect one error, I must click ADD button twice then info added to database

Comment: @bonapartenapoleon may be due to some javascript code. Appriciated for your up vote or choose as best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this...:)
I think it's working 100%...

```html
<a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">
<p align = 'center'><img src='image/add.png'></p>
</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
        <h3>ADD INFO</h3>
        <label for='mail' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Mail:</label>
        <input name='mail' id='mail' value='' placeholder='Mail' data-theme='a' type='text'>

        <label for='username' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Username:</label>
        <input name='username' id='username' value='' placeholder='Username' data-theme='a' type='text'>

        <label for='password' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Password:</label>
        <input name='password' id='password' value='' placeholder='Password' data-theme='a' type='text'>

        <button type="submit" name="Submit">ADD INFO</button>
    </div>
</form>

<?php
$db= mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
 if(!$db)
{
    echo "CAN'T CONNECT DATABASE";
    exit;
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("sctv_data2",$db);
if(!$db_selected)
{
    die("CAN'T USE THIS DATABASE: ".mysql_error());
}
if($_POST["mail"] !="" && $_POST["username"] != "" && $_POST["password"] !="" )
{
    $mail = $_POST["mail"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `login` VALUES ( '$mail','$username','$password')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$db);
}?>
```

Comment: You ought to explain why the OP should "try this" - especially when there is nothing in the above code to indicate where the original code differs from this!

Comment: I know brother his not getting PHP script that's why not inserting data so I write both in one file

Answer (score 0):

First your HTML Code:

```
<a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">
<p align = 'center'><img src='image/add.png'></p>
</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
<form action="popup.php" method="post">
    <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
        <h3>ADD INFO</h3>
        <label for='mail' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Mail:</label>
        <input name='mail' id='mail' value='' placeholder='Mail' data-theme='a' type='text'>

        <label for='username' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Username:</label>
        <input name='username' id='username' value='' placeholder='Username' data-theme='a' type='text'>

        <label for='password' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Password:</label>
        <input name='password' id='password' value='' placeholder='Password' data-theme='a' type='text'>

        <button type="submit" name="Submit">ADD INFO</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm assuming that the html code is working fine with the popup.

Then Your PHP Code.
Write the code at the top of the popup.php file. ( much nicer )
Also use PDO or Mysqli because Mysql is deprecated.

```
if (isset($_Post['username'])) {

    try {
        $db = array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'dbname' => 'sctv_data2',
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => ''
        );

        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db['host'] . ';dbname=' . $db['dbname'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "\n" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if ($_POST["mail"] != "" && $_POST["username"] != "" && $_POST["password"] != "") {
        $mail = $_POST["mail"];
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = md5($_POST["password"]);
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO login SET mail = :mail, username = :username, password = :password';

            $stm = $db->prepare('$sql');
            $stm->bindparam('mail' , $mail);
            $stm->bindparam('username' , $username);
            $stm->bindparam('password' , $password);
        $stm->execute();
    }
}
```

Now this is not the right way also. But it will get you futher.
Try OOP and wrap it in a class on a other page. That will be way nicer.
Also i've used MD5 hash for the password but i recommend using dcrypt insted.
Check the dbname because i'm not sure if its the right database name. Hope this will help you futher.